# Why doesn't (...)? regular expression capture the string?

Tags: c++, regex, qt5, qstring

I have a code where a `QString` is being modified using a regular expression:

```cpp
QString str; // str is the string that shall be modified
QString pattern, after; // pattern and after are parameters provided as arguments

str.replace(QRegularExpression(pattern), after);
```

Whenever I need to append something to the end of the string I use the arguments:

```cpp
QString pattern("$");
QString after("ending");
```

Now I have a case where the same pattern is being applied two times, but it shall append the string only once. I expected that this should work (I assume that the initial string doesn't end on `"ending"`):

```cpp
QString pattern("(ending)?$");
QString after("ending");
```

But if applied twice this pattern produces double ending: `"<initial string>endingending"`.

Looks like the `()?` expression is lazy, and it captures the expression in parentheses if I force it with a sub-expression before:

```cpp
QString pattern("string(ending)?$");
QString after("ending");

QString str("Init string");
str.replace(QRegularExpression(pattern), after);
// str == "Init ending"
```

What's wrong with the `"()?"` construction (why it is lazy) and how to achieve my goal?

I'm using Qt 5.14.0 (due to some dependencies I cannot use Qt6).

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you really need regular expressions? Why is `ending` marked as optional?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, yes, I need regular expressions because I'm solving a more general task where more tricky regular expressions are needed. The optional ending means that I want to have just a single ending even if the change is being applied multiple times.

Comment: I can repro this with standard library: https://godbolt.org/z/q7qbxhzoT

Comment: dropping capture group doesn't change anything: https://godbolt.org/z/7n18TfYsT

Comment: I don't even understand what you want to do. Can you explain your real goal (maybe including examples of before/after), without mentioning regular expressions?

Comment: @SebastianRedl, I have words and rules how to produce different wordforms of the same word. The words belong to classes, so generic patterns are applied to actual words. As long as some words can belong to different classes where the same rule is defined, it is possible that the same rule is being applied multiple times. But I don't want to get the "word" `"appendedededed"` after applying the pattern "$/ed" to the word "append" multiple times.

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to keep track of which rules have been applied and not apply them again, rather than making your regular expressions hideously complex and brittle so that they're idempotent.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, that is my long term plan, but for now it is easier to consider idempotent rules. Anyway, I wish to understand the issue above and I don't want to change the implementation just because the code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern like `(foo)?$` matches *twice* at the end of a string ending with `foo`. You can see easily in action in Perl or https://regex101.com/r/3Oqwo1/1 :

```
$ perl -E '$_ = "abcfoo"; while ($_ =~ /(foo)?$/g) { say "Matched |$&| from $-[0] to $+[0]"; }'

Matched |foo| from 3 to 6
Matched || from 6 to 6
```

Therefore you'll do two substitutions at the end, neglecting your purpose.

(A way to see this is that patterns match *between* characters:

```
            /-----------\
            v           v   first pattern matches here
| a | b | c | f | o | o |
                       ^ ^
                       \-/  second pattern matches here
```

If the "tail" is fixed-length, you can use a negative lookbehind, like already suggested: `(?<!foo)$`.

```
$ perl -E '$_ = "abcfoo"; while ($_ =~ /(?<!foo)$/g) { say "Matched |$&| from $-[0] to $+[0]"; }'
# no match
$ perl -E '$_ = "abcfie"; while ($_ =~ /(?<!foo)$/g) { say "Matched |$&| from $-[0] to $+[0]"; }'
Matched || from 6 to 6
```

Note that there's no `.*` before, nor `?` after the negative lookbehind. If you add them, you'll again break the matching:

```
$ perl -E '$_ = "abcfie"; while ($_ =~ /.*(?<!foo)$/g) { say "Matched |$&| from $-[0] to $+[0]"; }'
Matched |abcfie| from 0 to 6
Matched || from 6 to 6
```

Global matching will happen twice in `abcfie`, once matching the entire string, and again matching the empty string at the end (look at the offsets). This will result in 2 replacements.

```
perl -E '$_ = "abcfoo"; while ($_ =~ /(?<!foo)?$/g) { say "Matched |$&| from $-[0] to $+[0]"; }'
Matched || from 6 to 6
```

This will match at the very end of the string, resulting in a replacement that you don't want (string already ends in `foo`).

Answer (score 0):

What `?` in your regex is doing is that it is telling the regex engine that the string can **optionally** end with `ending`. Your question is a bit unclear, but if I understand it correctly, what you need instead is a `negative lookbehind`. Changing your pattern as follows should do the trick:

```cpp
QString pattern(".*(?<!ending)$");
```

This makes sure that it only matches strings that don't originally end with `ending`. You can play with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/YAIEF4/1).

Comment: That didn't help. I'm still getting double endings.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov this should work **without** the `.*` (although it seems like it's not supported in c++/gcc12) (not sure about Qt)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have explanation why it happens (so question in title is answered).

Basically `QRegExp::replace` or `std::regex_replace` finds two matches and performs two replacements. One where capture group matches ending and second times when capture group do not match and only ending is matched.

this is result of fact that `$` is just an assertion. It doesn't match any character, so can be used multiple times in index based search (when doing replace all).

Here is demo in clean C++ which illustrates the issue:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    auto r = std::regex{"(ending)?$"};
    auto after = "ending";
    while(getline(std::cin, s)) {
        std::cout << "s: " << s << '\n';
        std::cout << "replace: " << std::regex_replace(s, r, after) << '\n';
        for (auto i = std::regex_iterator{s.begin(), s.end(), r};
            i != decltype(i){};
            ++i) {
            std::cout << "found: " << i->str() << " capture: " << i->str(1);
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << "------------\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/e85ajb9aP

Now knowing root cause you can try address this issue.

I come up with: match whole string, using two capture grups one none greedy which will be used in `after`: re: `^(.*?)(ending)?$` and after: `$1ending`

https://godbolt.org/z/EKz4fEaT7

Comment: Could you please provide a spec that describes this behavior? "this is result of fact that $ is just an assertion" -- I'm still not convinced.

Comment: Any documentation about regular expression explain this. IMPO this is best: https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html Anyway I provided an experiment with `std::regex_iterator` which makes this pretty clear.

Comment: [Here is nice online tool](https://regex101.com/r/OSdPmi/1) which explain this in same way. Note each match explained on the right pane.